# Music Player Not Displaying Songs?

Tags: music-player, htc-desire-z

I am using a T-Mobile G2 running Android 2.3 and recently had to replace the phone with another as the old one was bad. I then launched the stock music player with my SD Card inserted and I viewing `"All Songs"` I noticed I was missing songs. I went to the Artist and could find the missing songs. What I am confused about is how to get the default Music Player to show those songs in the `All Songs` list.

I was looking at this question and the answer provided: [The music player keeps displaying deleted songs. How do I remove them or refresh the library?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10153/the-music-player-keeps-displaying-deleted-songs-how-do-i-remove-them-or-refresh)  I found the program and the cache was empty yet the `"storage data"` had info but when I went to clear it it gave me a warning saying this would clear all accounts and data etc. What will this clear if I choose this option? I do not want to lose other information.

Beyond clearing the media data is there any other steps that I should be using to try and get these songs to display?

It would be nice if in the options it gave a `refresh music library` option, other smart phones give this and I would assume Android would also but it is not there!

Note: This issue was not there on the old G2.

Comment: I think that's a sort of "generic" warning that shows up anytime you clear the data for a system service. I cleared my Media Storage data just now and I'm not noticing any other missing data (accounts, system settings, etc) but I'll dig around in some menus/apps for a bit to be sure.

Comment: @eldarerathis - Thank You Very Much. All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't looked exhaustively at the filesystem itself (didn't use `adb shell` or anything), but I'm fairly positive the warning is just a generic message that shows up whenever you clear data for an app or system service. I tried a couple of different apps and services and always saw the warning. After clearing my Media Storage data and unmounting/remounting my SD card I had:

- All of my music still available (after it had a chance to rescan)
- My Google Music account still set up and properly linked
- My ringtone still set to the correct song on my SD card
- All other accounts and settings normal

So basically, everything excepting the actual list of songs on my SD card was retained, and the list was refreshed after I remounted the SD card, as far as I can see.

Other than clearing Media Storage data, the only other thing I've tried to get my music to update is just unmounting and remounting the SD card (or using an app like [SD Rescan](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.bero.sdrescan) to do it for you, as mentioned in the other question). I've personally had kind of mixed results with this, but the clear data then remount cycle always seems to work.